# How to switch from one server connection to database engine

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working in SSMS. 
I have an object that I want to edit on several servers/databases simultaneously. 
I start with opening the object via Object explorer and editing/testing there. 
Once I am done, I go to Registered servers, and copy+paste the object code to update it on all the locations. 
Is there a faster way to do this? Right clicking and choosing Change connection only works with one Server at a time and does not allow to choose anything from the Database engine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SSMS has a SQLCMD mode.

[image]

By enabling it changing of the current connection can be part of the script:

```
:connect (local) 
SELECT name from sys.databases
-- run some other script

:connect anotherServer
SELECT name from sys.databases
-- run some other script
```

Another approach is Multi-database Query:

[image]

In such case, servers to be pre-grouped into folders based on your criteria

References:

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2855/sql-server-multi-database-query-with-registered-servers/
- https://www.sqlshack.com/use-sqlcmd-commands-ssms-query-editor/

Comment: Under local Server Groups I have a catalogue that I created that is called Development.
I am working on a SP that I have edited and now I want it to be altered on all the servers in the catalogue. 
If I write :Connect Development, I get an error that the server was not found. 
If I right click and choose New Query it works, naturally, but then I need to copy in all the text from my previous tab in the new one.

Comment: `:Connect`, unfortunately, cannot be used with *Server Groups* only with a real sql instance. Therefore, for your scenario perhaps is better to use a **multi-database query** and run a single script simultaneously on all servers that are part of some group